# How to catch mouse button events in another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am a newbie in WinForms and I have question about MouseDown and MouseUp events (sorry, if I duplicate it, but I cann't google it).
So, I have a PictureBox and paint cube on it. But I need to rotate it, using the mouse. I use auto-generated events MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove. First of them just change bool variable (it's stupid way to check, but I cann't find the better one).

```
    private void PictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RMBIsPressed = true;
    }

    private void PictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RMBIsPressed = false;
    }
```

In MouseMove I have do {} while(), that checks state of RMBIsPressed and repaint cube, if it's need.

```
    private void PictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePoint = MousePosition;
        Point mousePointNext;
        do
        {
            mousePointNext = MousePosition;
            if (mousePointNext != mousePoint)
            {
                if (mousePoint.X < mousePointNext.X)
                {
                    teta += deltaTeta;
                }
                else
                {
                    teta -= deltaTeta;
                }
                if (mousePoint.Y < mousePointNext.Y)
                {
                    phi += deltaPhi;
                }
                else
                {
                    phi -= deltaPhi;
                }
                PictureBox.Refresh();                    
                ViewTransformation();
                DrawCube();
            }
            mousePoint = MousePosition;
        } while (RMBIsPressed);
    }
```

When MouseUp event happens first time, everything is all right, but in next iteration RMBIsPressed is still true, even if I release RMB. It seems do while blocks the MouseUp event. My question is: can I create another thread, which will catch MouseUp and MouseDown events and change value of RMBIsPressed? If it's possible, please tell me how.

Comment: Why do you have a loop in your MouseMove handler? That handler is called every time the mouse is moved. This code will most likely completely lock up your UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `do-while` loop is not letting events being processed.

- Rename `mousePoint` to `lastPosition` and make it an instance variable.
- Set `lastPosition` in `MouseDown` and at end of `MouseMove`.
- Remove `do-while` in `MouseMove`

I would also change `PictureBox.Refresh` to `PictureBox.Invalidate`.  This will avoid flicker when mouse is moving very fast.

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted this.  This is the way it should be done.  You may also want to consider mentioning the 4th thing, that the code isn't checking for _which_ button is pressed, but the variable makes it seem like that's what's desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. It's strange, `PictureBox.Invalidate` don't clear `PictureBox`. I paint cube, using `Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox.Image)` and `DrawLine`.

Answer (score -1):

At the end of your `do {}` call `Application.DoEvents()`. That will process the windows messages in the buffer, which means the mouse up event will get processed.  You might also want to capture the mouse in mouse down.